# Validation rule for only numbers between 9 to12 digits, not accept special character and alphabets

Tags: validation-rule, validation

Pls help me I'm not able to understand how to write

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. This question shows no attempt to solve the problem for yourself or cite any searches you have done. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) for more detail. While someone has answered in this case, please make sure you follow the community expectations in future questions.

Answer (score 1):

Use this validation rule:

```
NOT( REGEX( Field, "[0-9]{9,12}"))
```

---

Regex `[0-9]{9,12}` is used to check for only digits (0-9) between 9 to 12 digits length.
If the Regex does not match the `Field` the validation rule will throw error.

Comment: Tq so much it's working